# How to call Salesforce public api from javascript in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, salesforcedx

I have created a public API in my org and I am trying to call from Javascript which is hosted as static resource in same org.
But Salesforce refused to connect public api.

I have tried CORS, Remote Site Settings, CSP Setting.

```
async function getUserAsync(name) 
{
  let response = await fetch('https://<api url>/services/apexrest/api-ws/',
{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: '{}'
    });
  let data = await response.json()
  return data;
}

getUserAsync()
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

> Refused to connect to 'https://*api_url*/services/apexrest/api-ws/'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "connect-src 'self' https://*org*.lightning.force.com
>   *.visualforce.com https://*org*.documentforce.com https://*org_instance*.salesforce.com".

**PS: Might be it is not good approach but I have a specific requirement.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Salesforce documentation -

> Previous versions of lightning:container allowed developers to specify
> the Content Security Policy (CSP) of the iframed content. We removed
> this functionality for security reasons. The CSP level of all pages is
> now set to high. This value provides the greatest security, because
> content can only be loaded from secure, approved domains. When
> lightning:container is used in Communities, the CSP setting in that
> community will be respected.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_limits.htm